# how to use user defined variables in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query, and i m trying to use the user defined variable @noVar in my where clause to show only the records with value 'Yes' on that variable.
but when I use Having @noVar = 'Yes' as in the query below, it returns 0 result.

```
SELECT svcreqdetail.id, svcreqcheckin.stime as checkin, @etime:=     time(timestampadd(minute, svcreqdetail.hours*60 , concat(caredate,' ', caretime))) as endtime, svcreqcheckout.stime as checkout, time_to_sec( if(svcreqcheckout.stime > svcreqcheckin.stime,
          timediff(svcreqcheckout.stime, svcreqcheckin.stime),
          addtime(timediff(svcreqcheckout.stime, svcreqcheckin.stime), '24:00:00.000000')))/3600 AS wrkHrs, svcreqdetail.hours,
svcreqstatus.status, @checkoutvar:= time_to_sec(timediff(svcreqcheckout.stime, @etime))/60 as checkoutvar,@noVar:= if (@checkoutvar <= 15,'Yes', 'No') as noVar, qualif
FROM svcreqdetail
LEFT JOIN svcreqcheckin ON svcreqcheckin.reqid = svcreqdetail.id
LEFT JOIN svcreqcheckout ON svcreqcheckout.reqid = svcreqdetail.id
JOIN svcreqstatus ON svcreqstatus.reqdid = svcreqdetail.id
WHERE (yearweek( caredate ) = yearweek( date_sub( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 week ) )
AND svcreqstatus.status != 'Incompleted'
AND svcreqstatus.status != 'Deleted')
having @noVar = 'Yes'
```

is there anyway i can test against that variable in my where clause. and thank you

Comment: where is the userdefined variable coming from? Normally you used a parameterized query / prepared statement. Can you provide info on langues used? or is this only a stored procedure?

Comment: it's defined withing the select clause, i ll be using php, but that @noVar variable must be calculated within the query, because i m defining it from a calculations of other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use user-defined variables in the `HAVING` clause like that.

One option would be to put your existing query (without the `HAVING` clause) into a sub-query and filter the results using a `WHERE` clause outside the sub-query, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  <your existing query goes here>
) AS sub_query
WHERE noVar = 'Yes'
```